# In Keeping with the tenor of time

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was reading an article where I came up with the phrase " in keeping with the tenor of time" but couldn't find its meaning on internet. Please explain the meaning of this phrase.

Comment: What article where? Can we see it? Can you quote more of it?

Answer (score 0):

"Tenor" has a sense other than a male singer with a high range:

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tenor)

> 2a: the drift of something spoken or written : [PURPORT](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/purport)

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/tenor) has:

> The character or usual pattern of something *Suddenly the tenor of the meeting changed...*

The expression "tenor of the time" refers to (some presumed) society's usual way of doing or thinking about things at some time.   The German loanword ***[zeitgeist](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zeitgeist)*** is often used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Spencer answered the question so I’ll uptick it.  However, he didn’t mention that the question said “tenor of time” when he talked about “the tenor of THE time” (emphasis added).

In my view, the expression “tenor of time” is ungrammatical and should read “tenor of the time”.  It is likely a misprint in the source or a misquote in the question.

The “tenor of the time” means the way things were being done at the time being referred to.